# Is it okay to store users in a saved JSON file?

Tags: json, authentication, hash

I want to create a very basic admin side for a site with very few users. From reading around, most people seem to be saying that storing users in a database allows for good scaling etc. For a small number of users, could anyone lay out any reasons why it would be a bad idea to store hashed users in a saved JSON file?

Comment: It depends on your context. For example, if you deployed to something without a persistent file system (e.g. Heroku) your data would be lost whenever the instance was restarted or redeployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will eventually very likely end-up reinventing the wheel - a database - but much buggier, much less performant, much harder to maintain and work with, etc. Use your own judgement, but keep in mind databases (especially relational databases management systems) are more than battle-tested and suit almost all apps “by default” (*i.e.* unless you have a very good reason to not use them, just use them).